# Равенство переменной одному из значений массива

Tags: массивы, php

Ребят, подскажите..
Мне надо проверить, есть ли в массиве элемент с таким же значение как и переменная в условии, например:

```
$arr[] = 10;
$arr[] = 20;
$arr[] = 30;
for($i = 0; $i++; $i<=2){
    if($arr[$i] == 30) echo "Совпадение!";
}
```

Так вот, есть ли способ проще? Например...

```
$arr[] = 10;
$arr[] = 20;
$arr[] = 30;
if($arr == 30) echo "Совпадение!";
```

Но я знаю что это не работает:D

Comment: @VenZell пожалуйста, добавте ваш ответ в ответы, что бы я мог его отметить закрытым)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php